# How to use QUndoCommand in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, undo-redo

Hello guys I am working on a graphics editor in which I transform QGraphicsItem using 3 different QSliders for scale, rotate Z-axis and rotate X or Y-axis. So how can I use QUndoCommand to achive it. I was reading documentation Push is used for pushing on the stack by which redo gets called.
What is mergewith method and how can I use it if I it is used for my concern.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.walletfox.com/course/qundocommandexample.php) will help you. But basically you need to subclass the QUndoCommand, and do the stuff which you want to undo later in your derived class.

Comment: Thanks vizhanyolajos :)